# Show result in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to haskell.

How can I return (x1,x2) and print it out from my code?

```
qqq x
   | x < 0  x1 = mod (-x) 10 
   | 1 < x && x < 99 x1 = mod x 10
   | x2 = mod x 10
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute `mod x 10` twice, or is one of those supposed to be a `div`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond It think he's trying to assign to two variables `x1` and `x2`, mistaking guard syntax for some sort of statement in the body of a function.

Comment: I.e., `x1` gets one of two values depending on the value of `x`, and `x2` always gets the value of `mod x 10`, then ..., and then they want to return `(x1, x2)`.

Comment: @chepner yes, You are absolutely right!

Comment: OK, thanks both - and apologies, it wasn't clear that you were asking about a compilation error as you didn't tell us about one. In Haskell there is no such thing as an "assignment" - you just define what things are. In your case it sounds like you can use either a `let ... in` construct or a `where` clause: eg `qqq x = (x1, x2) where x1 = ...; x2 = ...` (although in real Haskell code you'd put each definition on separate lines rather than using semicolons). There's much relevant info in [this chapter of the excellent LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using guards the wrong way. You seem to see these as `if` statements, that you then can use for *assignements*. In Haskell, you do not *assign* values to a variable, you *declare* these. You can work with:

```
qqq :: Integral a => a -> (a, a)
qqq x
   | x < 0 = (mod (-x) 10, x2)
   | 1 < x && x < 99 = (mod x 10, x2)
  where x2 = mod x 10
```

Here each guard thus has a condition before the equation sign (`=`), and at the right side returns a 2-tuple with as first item an expression for `x1`, and as second item `x2`.

You should also implement extra case(s) for `x == 1` and `x >= 99`, these are not covered by the two guards.